# If I shot a movie in 16:9 format in Ultra HD will the movie theatre play it?

Tags: movies, format, theater

Most films for cinema are not in 16:9 format. If I shot a movie in 16:9 format in Ultra HD, would there be any technical issue with getting it played in theatres?

Comment: I would suggest asking your local theatre... A few of your questions are very subjective, and probably not suitable for this site, which deals with answerable, specific questions. Have a look at the [faq] for guidance on how to ask questions here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AS to source material:

> As of 2009, the most common acquisition medium for digitally projected
>   features is 35 mm film scanned and processed at 2K (2048×1080) or 4K
>   (4096×2160) via digital intermediate. Most digital features to date
>   have been shot at 1920×1080 HD resolution using cameras such as the
>   Sony CineAlta, Panavision Genesis, or Thomson Viper. Cameras such as
>   the Arri Alexa can capture 2K resolution images, the Red Digital
>   Cinema Camera Company's Red One and Red Scarlet can record 4K, the Red
>   Epic 5K, and Sony's F65 CineAlta camera can record 4K down-sampled
>   from 8K. The marketshare of 2K projection in digital cinemas is over
>   98%. Development of the 4K Dalsa Origin was terminated by Dalsa
>   Corporation in 2008.

So recording in 16:9 is not gonna be a problem.

For playback:

> When all of the sound, picture, and data elements of a production have
>   been completed, they may be assembled into a Digital Cinema
>   Distribution Master (DCDM) which contains all of the digital material
>   needed for projection. The images and sound are then compressed,
>   encrypted, and packaged to form the Digital Cinema Package (DCP).

Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_cinema

For technical details, see this link for an overview:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Cinema_Package